# How to create duplicate and align a group of view in Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

As per screen shot i have registration form which have two fields like Text view and Edit text.

Normally i tried copy and paste for make view duplicate but when i use those command, All two views are overlapping on previous view with their constraints so it is more time consuming to clear all constraint and drag/paste view below.

so in a simple way, my question is:

1. How can i use copy and create views duplicate below that?
2. Can i Make a group of two objects like Textview & Edit text so i can use anywhere?

[image]

Comment: Add your xml file to get the Idea Regarding your design.

Comment: I think the issue is about using UI editor of Android Studio. Generally it is not good idea to use that, just editing xml is much more simple.

Comment: it may be ..using UI editor it makes complex.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a layout contain your repeat code like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="name" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Id Num" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="male" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="female" />
</RadioGroup>
```

and use  tag in your main layout like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.paredise.stackquestion.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_list" />
    <include layout="@layout/fragment_list"/>
    <include layout="@layout/fragment_list"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and also you can use listview if you have many time you use it in tandom

Comment: can you share me code that how can I create a layout contain for repeat code

Comment: using this tag I have to create more layout so I don't want to create more things , I just want copy and paste

Answer (score 1):

also you can using from styles in resourse-->value-->styles and Put your similar attribute in it :

```
<style name="myEditTextStyle">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="padding">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

and using style attribute in your view Just and write separate attribute for each one like EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edName"
        style="myEditTextStyle"
        android:text="name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edId"
        style="myEditTextStyle"
        android:text="Id Num" />

</LinearLayout>
```